# Number of layers in a resnet model

Tags: tensorflow

I have checkpoint file from a resnet model.

```
resnet_v1_101.ckpt
```

Now, I need to find the number of layers in this checkpoint file and detailed information about the layers.

How can I do that in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A checkpoint file doesn't have graph information. Therefore, you cannot get detailed information about the layers. However, if you saved your model by `tf.train.Saver().save(...)` and you didn't specify `write_meta_graph=False`, you should have a file like "resnet_v1_101.ckpt.meta". That is the `MetaGraphDef` file. You can import it like this:

```
tf.train.import_meta_graph('./resnet_v1_101.ckpt.meta')
```

You can now visualize the graph in tensorboard or use your own way to get information about the graph.

Comment: THanks..I downloaded the resnet from this link - http://download.tensorflow.org/models/resnet_v1_101_2016_08_28.tar.gz , but I could not find the .meta file within it. Any idea where can I get the meta file?

Comment: @user1050619 Sorry, I didn't know this is from Slim image classification. In that case you need to rebuild the model following [the instruction](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#fine-tuning-a-model-from-an-existing-checkpoint). Then you will be about to check the model.